# No packages found when I search for SQLite in NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, nuget

I'm following a YouTube tutorial called "Using SQLite in C#".

When he types "sqlite" in NuGet/Browse he gets these [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saBZ3.png)

But when I type it I get [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvxcz.png)

I couldn't find anything when I Googled about it. If anyone could help I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to the right of the package manager window. You can see a field called "Package Source" with a dropdownlist saying "nuget.org" in the example.

In your case this says "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages". Change this to "nuget.org" and you should find all the packages you need.

Answer (score 0):

please go to this path in visual studio:
tools->nuget package manager -> package manager console
add below code:
Install-Package SQLite -Version 3.13.0

Comment: I get this error: https://imgur.com/a/OrLOzxI